# Force user to select certificate in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate2

Even though the user of our web app selects a cert from their CAC at the start of the app, I have a need to force them to select again for verification.  I can get this to work on my local development machine with VS2012 development server but not after I deploy it:

```
 public X509Certificate2 selectCert()
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection sol = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2 sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Select Certificate", "Please select a certificate", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)[0];
        return sel;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a server-side code. Are you sure your web app users runs the code in their browsers?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - well, it is server side code and I'm trying to get the user to select one of their certs from the browser.

Comment: If I understand what you want, that will never work. According to my knowledge, there are currently no standarized html5 apis to access local cert stores. And the server side will never make the browser ask for a cert.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - thanks, I was just hoping that I could get IIS to ask for a cert again.

Comment: IIS asks for the certificate only because the ssl has the "require client certificate" option turned on. I don't know any way to force the server to ask for the cert once again in the same session. But you could consider a ClickOnce app delopled from the server. Such app is free to ask for the cert as it runs as the managed code at the client side.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - it is like in older web forms on the IIS server I can designate that an individual page, aspx, require SSL and it asks for a cert.  But that capability does not exist for MVC, I cannot see the views on the server IIS plugin.